# How to use a NuGetRestore Activity in MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, nuget-package-restore

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741198/modifying-tfs-process-template-to-implement-nuget-package-restore) asks the same question, but the answer is to use the new template that already makes use of the NugetRestore activity.

I tried to use the new template (TfvcTemplate.12.xaml) on a sample project and couldn't begin to get it to work.  I suspect its a rights issue somewhere (can't access the template during the build), but I couldn't solve it.  Edit: got a copy of that template and it still doesn't seem to call nuget; same problem - I need to make the NuGetRestore activity work.

In any case I have customizations already in place and only need to add in the new activity.
The problem is the activity has a "Solutions" string array property and I don't know how to pass the path to my solution.  If I pass {"$(SolutionRoot)\MySolution.sln"}, I see that unexpanded literal in the log:
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools\nuget.exe restore "$(SolutionRoot)\MySolution.sln" -NonInteractive

What can I pass as my solution path?

Comment: Even thought the template doesn't call that activity explicitly, it seems to be part of the MSBuild activity now, as is mentioned in [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bb358183-5552-4ee9-a6ef-528db24e65d0/how-to-use-the-nugetrestore-activity?forum=tfsbuild).